# How do I reassign a returned array to a preexisting array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization, return

This is the code, the sigmoid and dot methods return a 2d array. In the sigmoid and dot methods the Arrays, named `outputs`, are defined as so;
`double[][] outputs = new double[size1][size2];`, and are returned with `return outputs;`.
This section in the code returns the error "variable outputs might not have been initialized" which is caused by this peice of code;
`System.out.println("Outputs after training are: " + Arrays.toString(outputs));`.

```
double[][] outputs;
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    inputLayer = trainingInputs;
    outputs = sigmoid(dot(inputLayer, synapticWeights));
}
System.out.println("Outputs after training are: " + Arrays.toString(outputs));
```

I'd like to get rid of the error so the array `outputs`can be printed into console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared a variable **outputs** it may get initialised in your **for** loop. You should initialize it with null at the time of declaration. Your code should be like this. Code snippet below :

```
double[][] outputs = null;
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
  inputLayer = trainingInputs;
  outputs = sigmoid(dot(inputLayer, synapticWeights));
}
System.out.println("Outputs after training are: " + Arrays.toString(outputs));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not what you think.

You are assigning the array the correct way.  The *real problem* is that the Java compiler thinks that the code doesn't *always* assign a value to `outputs`.   (That's what the  compilation error actually means ...)

Why?

There are two ways to think about this:

- Intuitively, the compiler can't figure out that that the loop body for

  `for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){...}`

  is always going to run at least once.
- The technically correct explanation is that the JLS *definite assignment* rules do not say that `outputs` has been definitely been assigned before it is used.  [JLS Chapter 16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-16.html) deals with this.

---

Here are two possible fixes:

- Explicitly initialize the variable.

  ```
  double[][] outputs = null;
  for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
      inputLayer = trainingInputs;
      outputs = sigmoid(dot(inputLayer, synapticWeights));
  }
  System.out.println("Outputs after training are: " + Arrays.toString(outputs));
  ```
- If this was real code (not a cut down example), you could observe that the loop is redundant and get rid of it!

  ```
  double[][] outputs;

  inputLayer = trainingInputs;
  outputs = sigmoid(dot(inputLayer, synapticWeights));
  System.out.println("Outputs after training are: " + Arrays.toString(outputs));
  ```

Comment: Thank you I need the loop for later use, this was very helpful.